# MySQL workbench: get rid off the backticks around every field

Tags: mysql-workbench

Is there a setting to avoid backticks around every fieldname when writing a view or sp ?

I can't find any setting.

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no setting for that. Generated code has to play safe to avoid any trouble when running queries and because identifiers allow for many unusual characters (basically the entire Unicode BMP is allowed, except some control chars), it is necessary to quote them with backticks.

In some places MySQL Workbench does an analysis to see if quotes are required, but that's not a general approach. And since this is usually a no-brainer, no measure was taken to change that behavior.